# Detecting if at least one input (as array) is filled in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a group of inputs like `<input type="text" name="clients[]" />` that are loaded via AJAX. Before the user submits the form, I need to check if at least one of them has been filled. I don't know how to do this if is an array.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind a function to the submit event for the form like this:

```
// assuming #foo is the form and each grouped element has classname bar
// also, this assumes that your form is not loaded by AJAX, but only the elements
// contained in it
$('#foo').submit(function() {
    var elements = $("input[name='clients[]']");
    var validated = false;
    elements.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            validated = true;
            return false; // will break the each
        } else {
            validated = false;
        }
    });
    return validated;
});
```

[Live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/cAM3v/)

Comment: are you NOT forgetting a `.live` function due to ajax returned strings?

Comment: No. the elements are bound *after* the form is submitted, so `live()` would not be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var $filledTextboxes = $(":text[name='clients[]']").filter(function(){
   return $.trim($(this).val()) != "";
});
if($filledTextboxes.size() == 0)
   alert("All are empty");
else
   alert("Not all are empty");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you Edgar. This will work with loaded via ajax inputs? Thank you!