# jQuery check that at least five inputs have data in them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of inputs on the page and need to force that at least 5 items have been filled. And if not then show a message saying you must fill at least 5. So far I have tried the following but it just shows the error over and over again. What's the proper way of doing this?

```
$('div.inputs input').each(function(i) {
    $input = $(this);
    while (i < 5) {
        if ($($input).val() == '') {
            alert('must fill at least 5 items!');
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting if at least one input (as array) is filled in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908199/detecting-if-at-least-one-input-as-array-is-filled-in-jquery)

Comment: So frustrating! It's not a duplicate because it has a similar context or intended outcome. The issue is I'm looking to fix **MY ISSUE** with **MY CODE** so therefore other questions answers are not relevant unless I'm only interested in getting a quick win and not the answer to my question.

Comment: The your question is too localized since I don't think anyone else will ever have the same code as you. It might be different if you asked *specifically* what is wrong with your code, but you asked *what is the proper way of doing this*, which was answered before.

Comment: I can't be expected to have issues that can only be fixed when another person in the world can also benefit... It is what it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can create a better selector, and then:</strike>

```
if ($('div.inputs input[value!=""]').length < 5) {
  alert('must fill at least 5 items!');
}
```

Explanation:

The `div.inputs input[value!=""]` selector selects all input fields which has something in the `value` attribute, and then you can fetch the length of the selected items.

The previous solution works (somehow), but I recommend a better one:

```
if ($('div.inputs input').filter(function () { return $(this).val().length > 0; }).length < 5) {
  alert('must fill at least 5 items!');
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works tbh. Entering a value into the inputs does not change their `value` attribute. It seems that jQuery is inspecting the property of the element, not the attribute. This is bad, since the other way round (selecting elements with empty value `$('input[value=""]')`), jQuery (or Sizzle) seems to use the internal `querySelectorAll` method, which does not work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/pQmRC/

Comment: Yes, I was wandering about the same since I posted :)

Comment: Mmmh... seems it's even more confusing than I thought. `$("input").not('[value=""]')` (using internal methods) works the same as `$('input[value!=""]')` does... I think, in the end, it might be better to use `.filter()` ;)

Comment: Your latest answer with the filter does not work for me! Using latest version of jQuery too.

Comment: @Cameron check it again, first time a parenthesis was missing.

Comment: Needs to be `if ...length < 5` (not `> 5`). Also, you can make it more efficient by saying `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Nope still not working for me using the filter. Works with the other one though.

Answer (score 2):

The methods shown in KARASZI István's answer are neater, but as far as explaining what is wrong with your code and how you might fix it, the (main) problem is that the `while` condition:

```
while(i<5)
```

...is evaluating a variable, `i`, that is not changed by the contents of the loop. On the first iteration of the `.each()` loop `i` is 0 so the `while` condition is true *and remains true* so you get an endless loop.

To keep the general structure of your code and loop through each input testing the values you could do something like this:

```
var filled = 0;

$('div.inputs input').each(function (i) {
    if (this.value != '') {
        filled++;
        if (filled === 5)
           return false;
    }
});

if (filled < 5) {
    alert('must fill at least 5 items!');
}
```

That is, for each input that is not blank increment a counter, and then check the counter after the loop. Note that returning `false` from within the `.each()` callback function stops the `.each()` loop immediately; no need to keep counting once we've reached the minimum 5 non-empty values.